# Getting Image Uri

Tags: android, image, uri

I am trying to share an image but I am unsure of how to get the image URI for here:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  intent.setType("image/jpeg");
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, [image URI]);
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image with"));
  }
}
```

Below I have all of the code where the above was taken out of.

public class ImagePagerActivity extends BaseActivity {

```
private ViewPager pager;
private DisplayImageOptions options;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.ac_image_pager);

    Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.locations, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
    list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
    getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(1);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String[] imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);
    int pagerPosition = bundle.getInt(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, 0);

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
        .cacheOnDisc()
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACT)
        .build();

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(imageUrls));
    pager.setCurrentItem(pagerPosition);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    imageLoader.stop();
    super.onStop();
}

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private String[] images;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    ImagePagerAdapter(String[] images) {
        this.images = images;
        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View container) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View view, int position) {
        final FrameLayout imageLayout = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager_image, null);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
        final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(null);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image with"));
              }
            }); 

        imageLoader.displayImage(images[position], imageView, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted() {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(FailReason failReason) {
                String message = null;
                switch (failReason) {
                    case IO_ERROR:
                        message = "Input/Output error";
                        break;
                    case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                        message = "Out Of Memory error";
                        break;
                    case UNKNOWN:
                        message = "Unknown error";
                        break;
                }
                Toast.makeText(ImagePagerActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete() {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ImagePagerActivity.this, R.anim.fade_in);
                imageView.setAnimation(anim);
                anim.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled() {
                // Do nothing
            }
        });

        ((ViewPager) view).addView(imageLayout, 0);
        return imageLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View container) {
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {

    if (itemPosition == 0){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
    return true;
}
}
```

If anybody can help that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

This is how u get URI for an image in your drawable:

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/" + R.drawable.your_image);
```

Comment: Can you give me the code I would use using my code? I am new to android and I am not sure what to do.

Comment: The problem is idk where the image is being saved so idk how to access it.

Comment: This method will work if your image is present in RES > DRAWABLE (any drawable folder). All drawables can be accessed in your java code by using R.drawable.image_name.

Comment: Can you tell me where MY image is present if you look at my code?

Comment: Is your image stored in SDCARD or in a drawable folder? By looking at your code, i cannot say where ur image is stored!

Comment: Honestly I do not know where it is stored. I believe it is stored in the cache because I load them from a url.

Comment: so basically u are trying to download the image from the web and share it again using your app?

Comment: That would be one way to do it.

Comment: Yes, download it to a specific location on your SDCARD, get its URI and then pass it to your intent object.